# I need a Faster way to update a DataSet in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataset

In VB I am getting some information from one dataSet and updating another.
There is something close to 200k records in the DataSet and it is taking a very long time. Close to 2 minutes per thousand records.

Any suggestions on a faster method, please feel free to inform me.

**EDIT - I have determined that the reason it was taking so long was partly due to updating the DataSet every time a new row was added and outputting the counts of those records to a label.  I moved the UPDATE outside of the loop and got an error.  Removed the ReportProgress and the label output and the error goes away.  So I guess now I am looking for suggestions on how send this information to a progress bar or a label without it failing. I think outputting to a label takes longer than the actual row creation.

```
Private Sub bgwUpdate_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwUpdate.DoWork

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        Dim intIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim strName As String
        Dim dblLatDegrees As Double
        Dim dblLatMinutes As Double
        Dim dblLatSeconds As Double
        Dim strLatDirection As String
        Dim dblLonDegrees As Double
        Dim dblLonMinutes As Double
        Dim dblLonSeconds As Double
        Dim strLonDirection As String

        ' Loop through all records in the CO DataTable
        For Each CORow As DataRow In TowersDataSet.CO

            strName = CStr(TowersDataSet.CO.Company_NameColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Company_Name"))
            dblLatDegrees = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Latitude_DegreesColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Latitude_Degrees"))
            dblLatMinutes = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Latitude_MinutesColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Latitude_Minutes"))
            dblLatSeconds = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Latitude_SecondsColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Latitude_Seconds"))
            strLatDirection = CStr(TowersDataSet.CO.Latitude_DirectionColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Latitude_Direction"))

            dblLonDegrees = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Longitude_DegreesColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Longitude_Degrees"))
            dblLonMinutes = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Longitude_MinutesColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Longitude_Minutes"))
            dblLonSeconds = CDbl(TowersDataSet.CO.Longitude_SecondsColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Longitude_Seconds"))
            strLonDirection = CStr(TowersDataSet.CO.Longitude_DirectionColumn.Table.Rows(intIndex).Item("Longitude_Direction"))

            ' Create a new row with the information we gathered
            Dim updateRow As GPS_FunDataSet1.LocationsRow
            updateRow = GPS_FunDataSet1.Locations.NewLocationsRow

            updateRow.name = strName
            updateRow.type = "Tower"
            updateRow.latitude = convert.toDecimal(CStr(dblLatDegrees) + " " + CStr(dblLatMinutes) + " " + CStr(dblLatSeconds) + strLatDirection)
            updateRow.longitude = convert.toDecimal(CStr(dblLonDegrees) + " " + CStr(dblLonMinutes) + " " + CStr(dblLonSeconds) + strLonDirection)

            ' Add the row to the DataTable
            GPS_FunDataSet1.Locations.Rows.Add(updateRow)

            ' Update the Actual database
            Try
                LocationsBindingSource.EndEdit()
                LocationsTableAdapter.Update(GPS_FunDataSet1.Locations)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Failure")
            End Try

            bgwUpdate.ReportProgress(intIndex + 1)
            intIndex += 1
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: You simply have to update the database once after the loop, not always. So move `LocationsTableAdapter.Update(GPS_FunDataSet1.Locations)` behind the loop. Then all can be updated/inserted in one batch.

Comment: I moved just that line to after the loop and I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: I would recommend changing the title of your question to better match the question you are asking now.